# Rails/heroku: how to make work my app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails (2.3.5) app and I had to make some changes on it, involving changing the db. So, locally it's working fine, but when I tryied to push it to heroku I'm having a "Application Error" on my browser when I'm trying access the app. I've pushed the new code, bootstraped and filled the heroku db with my local project.

This is what I got with "heroku logs", any ideas? :

```
C:\Sites\takenetqd>heroku logs
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 levels...
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-11-25T15:54:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-25T15:54:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-25T16:04:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:04:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T16:04:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 50841 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /app/app/controllers/
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'

2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_
or_load'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_o
n'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_
dependency'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 levels...
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-25T16:04:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-25T16:15:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:15:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to s
tarting
2011-11-25T16:15:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 53066 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /app/app/controllers/
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'

2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_
or_load'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_o
n'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_
dependency'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 levels...
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-11-25T16:15:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-25T16:15:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-25T16:25:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:25:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /app/app/controllers/
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'

2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.
3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_o
n'
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_
dependency'
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T16:35:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:35:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T16:35:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 38632 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /app/app/controllers/
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'

2011
-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_o
n'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_
or_load'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_
dependency'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 levels...
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-11-25T16:35:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-25T16:35:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-25T16:46:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:46:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T16:47:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 53480 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-25T16:47:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-25T16:57:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T16:57:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T16:57:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-25T17:07:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-25T17:07:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-25T17:07:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 6130 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /app/app/controllers/
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'

2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_
or_load'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_o
n'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_
dependency'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 levels...
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-11-25T17:07:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-25T17:07:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: can you paste the contents of sms_controller.rb please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a syntax error in one of your controllers:

```
sms_controller.rb:232: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your sms controller and make sure that each `def`[1] is closed off with an `end`

The log file doesn't have to be that intimidating. Note that the critical information is stated after the app has been created and then started, because that's where the problems started, and the most vital information is closer to the top. The first line after that states the syntax error. All of the subsequent lines are errors that will disappear once the top error is fixed.

[1] Not necessarily a `def` - could be a block, a loop, iteration etc.